# How to set command timeout in yii?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am struggling to find where to set the command timeout in Yii for MySql database (some queries are taking a  while to run).

In the source code the file protected/config/main.php has these settings:

> 'db'=>array(          'connectionString' =>
>   'mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx;port=xxx;timeout=100;',            'emulatePrepare'
>   => true,          'username' => 'xxx',            'password' => 'xxx',            'charset' => 'utf8',            'schemaCachingDuration'=>3600,      ),

The timeout seems to apply to connections, and command timeout default is 30 seconds (that's the one I need to increase).

Web pages fetching from db usually fail with Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in \YiiRoot\framework\db\CDbCommand.php on line 508.

line 508 is

> $this->_statement->execute();

so obviously is a query timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a mysql error, it is a php error. `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds` is set by the php.ini setting `max_execution_time` the default is 30. You can either change your php.ini file, or you can adjust it with .htaccess or on the individual function you can use the `set_time_limit()` command.

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Yeah, that made the trick, I am not exactly an expert in PHP, thanks!